# Gravity Forms Prevent duplicate time slots

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a photography booking page which contains a list of packages, which when selected are booked on the Gravity Form.

When the user books a "time slot" for a particular day, I need that time slot to become unavailable.

I have set the field "Available Time Slots" to not allow duplicates, however this is not preventing the time slot from becoming unavailable once booked.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your form is configured, you might find my plugin which allows you to limit how many times an individual choice may be selected to be helpful: https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-limit-choices/

Comment: thank you for the link.  I am looking at it.  Do you perhaps have an idea of how I can configure it to limit the number of times a time slot can be seleted for a particular date?

Comment: This snippet allows you to create "field groups" so that whatever fields are in that group with the limited choice created a unique option for that choice. For example, if you add a Drop Down field and a Date field, each choice is unique to the selected date. This would allow you to limit each choice to once per date.

https://gist.github.com/spivurno/8ca209fbb5068e62655ddf91678830a3

Comment: Thank you. Would the only editable section be:
`new GP_Limit_Choices_Field_Groups( array(
    'form_id'   => 1485,
    'field_ids' => array( 1, 2 )
) );`